# getInitialNotification of React Native Firebase returns notification object only for first push notification

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have a weird problem with @react-native-firebase/messaging. I recently updated to v6 and everything works well on iOS and on Android everything works well except for one thing.

When getting multiple push notifications the following is the case:

1. Clicking on one notification opens the app and `getInitialNotification()` gives me the clicked notification, so I can handle it
2. When closing the app completely and then clicking on one of the other notifications the app opens again, but `getInitialNotification()` returns `null`

It seems like opening the app with one notification eats the data of all the other notifications as well.
I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I have no clue where I can search for the issue.

Some information about the setup

- I removed react-native-splash-screen (didn't change anything)
- I am on the most recent versions of @react-native-firebase/app and /messaging ("@react-native-firebase/app": "8.2.0", "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "7.4.2")
- React Native is on version 0.62.2
- The app is calling `getInitialNotification()` in a `useEffect`, so after the first render of the navigation tree

Comment: any luck? i'm experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage.notification,
      );
      navigation.navigate(remoteMessage.data.type);
    });
```

Add this listner

https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications

Comment: Thank you for your response. I implemented that already. However it is explicitly when starting the app via a push notification and `onNotificationOpenedApp` is only being called when the app is already running.
Do I get this wrong? Or is it maybe a timing issue then?

Comment: Yes, sometime it happens, when App is already on background and opened from Push notification It take time.
In my case, when I press on notification, in background application is in different Stack and Tab, onNotification I'm redirecting to other deeply nested stack. So sometime it takes time. But in debug mode not in APK build. In APK it take fraction of time depending on network load. But mostly it redirect smoothly ( APK Build ). So if you're testing in debug mode / device connected to npm.it will take time. Beside I've to manage 15 different scenarios on Notification.